# Searching Dictionary Values & Keys & Displaying in UITableView issues

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to update my search display controller but right now, I have it set up like this :

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Documents"
                                                 ofType:@"plist"];

searchDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
allsearchDictKeys = [searchDict allKeys];
```

I search through it with a NSPredicate

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [searchDict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSString *obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([key isEqualToString:searchText] || [obj isEqualToString:searchText] ) {
        [searchResults addObject:key];
        NSLog(@"search is %@", searchResults);
    }}];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
return YES;
}
```

And display the results in a tableview like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *defaultIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:defaultIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:defaultIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [searchDict valueForKey:cell.textLabel.text];

return cell;
}
```

I would like to be able to search both the value *and* keys so I have implemented this:

```
allsearchDictValues = [searchDict allValues];

//Trying to search complete plist where searchArray is NSMutableArray
searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[searchArray addObjectsFromArray:allsearchDictKeys];
[searchArray addObjectsFromArray:allsearchDictValues];
```

And search it this way :

```
 NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@", searchText];
searchResults = [[searchArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

But then the table view cell.textLabel just displays the value and nothing in the detailTextLabel. So how do I search both the values and keys of a dictionary but keep the cell format the same where the key is the cell.textLabel and the value is the cell.detailTextLabel

Comment: How you search has nothing to do with how you choose to display the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSDictionary lets you enumerate both the keys and values it contains. You could consider something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *searchResults = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
- (void)enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSString *obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([key isEqualToString:searchText] || [obj isEqualToString:searchText] ) {
        [searchResults addObject:key];
}
```

And now your search results contains the keys for the dictionary where either the key or the object was matched to your search string.

Comment: I am sorry. It seems Hot Licks has a point. Its not the searching I have a problem with, in fact it's working great when I just search keys, it's displaying it appropriately. Being a newbie as I am i would like to keep the method within shouldReload. I have edited my question. maybe you can help?

Comment: It's a way of searching keys and values in a dictionary in one pass. And if you are only looking for one item, this lets you stop further enumeration by setting `*stop = YES` within the block.

Comment: okay thanks. where do i put this? I get 'expected method' body error

Comment: You use it where you want to generate searchResults.

Comment: Thanks. Figured it out